# Only the wallpaper and cursor show on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mouse, desktop-background, cursor

I tried to make some effects but now I can ONLY see a wallpaper and cursor, nothing else. I can normally use right click button also, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Could you clarify on "make some effects"?

Comment: I was making effects with compiz.. I checked the cube (or something else I don't remember) and then it asked if I wanna remove something else, because I can't use that effect if I don't remove that another effect first.. I hope you can understand and help :/

Comment: right, your issue was probably with the cube (unity doesn't support this at all). Remi's answer should fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

To reset the default settings, you can enter

```
unity --reset
```

The problem you may have is to get to a terminal : if you cannot access the dash, you can try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>. And if this does work, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, and log in.